# How can I add a login account directly from Phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to code my own backoffice and I need to add a login system. I found a working one on google and it's working fine but the only problem is that it only works with hashed passwords.

That means if I want to add a new user in the backoffice, I need to use the regiser.php file instead of making one directly on the Phpmyadmin table. The login system only reads hashed password so if i try to write it normally in table and then i try to login it says incorrect password.

I'm still learning so I don't really know how to make my own login system.

Can somebody help me please,
Thank you,
Arty

I tried to remove the hash system but then the password_verify stops working, has I read online it only works with password_hash

```
//REGISTER.PHP 

// Prepare an insert statement

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){

// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password);

$param_username = $username;

$param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 

// Creates a password hash


//LOGIN.PHP

// Bind result variables

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);

if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
```

Comment: If the login system you've found is using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` - it's doing it right, don't try to circumvent it!

Comment: You can generate salted hash and manually insert into DB, but it is not recommended and definitely don't do it in live production system. https://3v4l.org/A7lG5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you will not want to do this in an actual login system, but for experimenting purposes you can remove the hashed password feature.

The code will be something like this:

```
//REGISTER.PHP 

// Prepare an insert statement
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){

// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password);

$param_username = $username;
$param_password = $password; 

// Creates a password hash

//LOGIN.PHP

// Bind result variables

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $db_password);

 //COMPARE FORM PASSWORD and PASSWORD FROM DB
if($password == $db_password)) {

...
```